# Get Highest number from array using for loop

Tags: php, max

I am trying to get highest number from `array`. But not getting it. I have to get highest number from the array using `for` loop.

```
<?php
$a =array(1, 44, 5, 6, 68, 9);
$res=$a[0];
for($i=0; $i<=count($a); $i++){
    if($res>$a[$i]){
        $res=$a[$i];
    }
}
?>
```

I have to use `for` loop as i explained above. Wat is wrong with it?

Comment: `$res = max($a);` not working for you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
<?php

    $a = array(1, 44, 5, 6, 68, 9);
    $res = 0;

    foreach($a as $v) {
        if($res < $v)
            $res = $v;
    }

    echo $res;

?>
```

Output:

```
68
```

In your example you just did 2 things wrong:

```
$a = array(1, 44, 5, 6, 68, 9);
$res = $a[0];

for($i = 0; $i <= count($a); $i++) {
              //^ equal is too much gives you an offset!

      if($res > $a[$i]){
            //^ Wrong condition change it to < 
          $res=$a[$i];
      }

}
```

**EDIT:**

With a for loop:

```
$a = array(1, 44, 5, 6, 68, 9);
$res = 0;

for($count = 0; $count < count($a); $count++) {

    if($res < $a[$count])
        $res = $a[$count];

}
```

Comment: Sorry i have to use for loop

Comment: @pawankumar updated my answer, but your code is with a for loop and i showed you where to fix it, added now and example how it should look like

Comment: I need only highest single number (68).

Comment: @pawankumar `$res` is equal 68 it is that number! print it with echo

Comment: outside for loop . echo $res; i got answer. Thanks again

Answer (score 3):

What about:

```
<?php
    $res = max(array(1,44,5,6,68,9));
```

([docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.max.php))

Answer (score 1):

you should only remove the = from $i<=count so it should be

```
<?php $a =array(1,44,5,6,68,9);
$res=$a[0];
for($i=0;$i<count($a);$i++){
  if($res<$a[$i]){
   $res=$a[$i];
  }
}
?>
```

the problem is that your loop goes after your arrays index and the condition is reversed.

Answer (score 0):

The `max()` function will do what you need to do :

```
$res = max($a);
```

More details [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.max.php).

Comment: sorry i am using for loop

Comment: Sorry. I missed that bit.

Answer (score -1):

## Suggest using Ternary Operator

(Condition) ? (True Statement) : (False Statement);

```
    <?php
      $items = array(1, 44, 5, 6, 68, 9);
      $max = 0;
      foreach($items as $item) {
        $max = ($max < $item)?$item:$max;
      }
      echo $max;
    ?>
```